# In bash, how can I check a string for partials in an array?

Tags: regex, arrays, bash, match

If I have a string:

```
s='path/to/my/foo.txt'
```

and an array

```
declare -a include_files=('foo.txt' 'bar.txt');
```

how can I check the string for matches in my array efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

You could loop through the array and use a [bash substring check](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/041)

```
for file in "${include_files[@]}"
do 
   if [[ $s = *${file} ]]; then
     printf "%s\n" "$file"
   fi
done
```

Alternately, if you want to avoid the loop and you only care that a file name matches or not, you could use the `@` form of bash [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob). The following example assumes that array file names do not contain `|`.

```
shopt -s extglob
declare -a include_files=('foo.txt' 'bar.txt');
s='path/to/my/foo.txt'
printf  -v pat "%s|" "${include_files[@]}"
pat="${pat%|}"
printf "%s\n" "${pat}"
#prints foo.txt|bar.txt
if [[ ${s##*/} = @(${pat}) ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For an exact match to the file name:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="path/to/my/foo.txt";
ARR=('foo.txt' 'bar.txt');
for str in "${ARR[@]}"; 
do 
  # if [ $(echo "$s" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}') == "$str" ]; then
  if [ $(basename "$s") == "$str" ]; then  # A better option than awk for sure...
     echo "match"; 
  else 
     echo "no match"; 
  fi; 
done
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use awk to strip off the part before the last slash. Bash parameter expansion can do this `"${s##*/}"` or the `basename` utility.

Comment: Indeed. Didn't occur to me right away. Thanks. I have added one of these nice options...